# CefSharp - загрузить файл по захардкодженому адресу без отображения OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium

Итак имеется:

1. CefSharp.Winforms
2. Некий сайт где есть кнопка Upload File, которая открывает OpenFileDialog

Вы открываете сайт и жмете на аплоад(вручную). OpenFileDialog должен НЕ ОТКРЫТСЯ, но просто принять как резалт адресс захардкодженый путь к файлу.

Этот функционал был доступен в 2014 году: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/342/commits/c11fe8e4e97179ff4073208c13f9ff29e61bab79

Тогда это реализовалось следующим путем:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace CefSharp.Example
{
    public class TempFileDialogHandler : IDialogHandler
    {
        public bool OnFileDialog(IWebBrowser browser, string title, string defaultFileName, List<string> acceptTypes, out List<string> result)
        {
            result = new List<string> { Path.GetRandomFileName() };
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

после чего это дело должно было быть присвоено в инстанс браузера:

```
Browser.DialogHandler = new TempFileDialogHandler(files);
```

сейчас список параметров изменился и выглядит так:

```
public bool OnFileDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefFileDialogMode mode, string title, string defaultFilePath, List<string> acceptFilters, int selectedAcceptFilter, IFileDialogCallback callback)
```

**То есть возможность задавать резалт нашего OpenFileDialog была убрана.** Реализовать это мне все равно нужно...

Итак вопрос: как это обойти и реализовать такую возможность сейчас?

Желательно без использования WinApi.

Пример страницы с кнопкой:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept

Comment: Мне кажеться что это связанно с политикой безопасности, и было убрано специально, так что удалить диалог скорее всего не удастся, мое мнение. Но можно слазить в исходники Цефа, и отрубить навсегда диалог там.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь это делается так:

```
public class TempFileDialogHandler : IDialogHandler
{
    public bool OnFileDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, CefFileDialogMode mode, string title, string defaultFilePath, List<string> acceptFilters, int selectedAcceptFilter, IFileDialogCallback callback)
    {
        var files = new List<string> { "C:\\tmp\\1111.bmp" };
        callback.Continue(0, files);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как и обещал, я поставлю вознаграждение за вопрос завтра и отмечу этот ответ как победителя.